# How can I delete event parameters in Flurry without deleting the event?

Tags: flurry

How can I delete event parameters in Flurry without deleting the event? I made some mistakes on the keys & values for the parameters, so now they look funny. I know I can delete the events, but I want to delete only the parameters and keep the events. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now, you have either to delete the event or write the helpdesk support@flurry.com, but the answer of the helpdesk takes a while.

I used Flurry but now I implemented [Localytics](http://www.localytics.com/)
and IMHO the better product, although that "promotion" wasn't the answer to your question, just as additional info. ;-)

cheers endo

**EDIT:** The next time the event occurs, it's set new.

Comment: If I delete the event, it will never show up again, right? Is that how Flurry works?

Comment: The next time the event occurs, it's set new.

Comment: If you delete the event, here is how to get it back again: [Flurry - Deleted events do not appear again](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11792272/383414)

Answer (score 2):

To delete or hide an event in flurry, go to manage -> events -> select specific event