# Flurry - Deleted events do not appear again

Tags: flurry

In an attempt to clean up test records, i had cleaned up all events in Flurry administration. However i was hoping that all future use of the same events will appear in the events captured by Flurry.

However its 24 hours since i had deleted and have used the application. It still does not appear in Flurry.

Do events deleted in Flurry - never appear again?

Comment: This is really a good question and I am also looking for the solution.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There is a way to restore deleted events.
Using Chrome developer tools or Firebug on page "Manage > Events" find the line `<div id="createNewEvent" style="display: none; ">`, remove style attribute and now you can create new event with the old name you want to restore.

Comment: brilliant! no need to contact support.

Comment: What an Extraordinary exploit :)

Comment: Wuau, almost 2 years later and this hack still works!

Comment: This is such a fantastic hack. I love it.

Comment: No longer valid

Answer (score 10):

The deleted events are in fact blacklisted and won't appear anymore on your analytics page. You should contact the support team and they have the ability to remove those restrictions so you can see them back in your account.

Comment: I hope their support acts fast. I missed out my first week's worth of data after release thanks to this stupid design flaw. I've told them they at least need to add a warning with a checkbox that says "blacklist these events" when deleting them. That's like deleting a file and the OS never allowing you to have a file of the same name again in that location.